# Issue responsive lay-out

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I am facing a problem that I cannot solve it bymyself I have spend hours tweaking and tweaking but the problem is stil there. The problem is the checkboxes wont show beneath each other when resizing the screen of my browser (google chrome latest version) and also the button is not centering right. See image [image]

HTML CODE:

```
<form method="post" action="#" id="newsletterform" data-mailchimp="xtrue">
          <div>
            <label for="newsletter-name"></label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Name" class="input-field" id="newsletter-name" name="newsletter-name" value="">
          </div>
          <div>
            <label for="newsletter-email"></label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="e-mail" class="input-field" id="newsletter-email" name="newsletter-email" value="">
          </div>
          </br>
          <div class="input-check">
            <label for="newsletter-checkbox1">
            <input type="checkbox" class="input-check" id="newsletter-checkbox" name="newsletter-checkbox" value="check">
            <span style="width:120px;margin-top:30px;display:inline-block;clear">some text to check</span>
            <input type="checkbox" class="input-check" id="newsletter-checkbox" name="newsletter-checkbox2" value="check">
            <span style="width:120px;margin-top:30px;display:inline-block;">some text to check2</span>
          </div>
           <div>
          <a id="button-newsletter" href="#" title="Subscribe now">Subscribe</a>
        </form>
</div>
```

CSS CODE:

```
.container {
    position:relative
}

#newsletterform {
    float: right;
    margin-top: -87px
}

#newsletterform div {
    height: 45px;
    float: left;
    margin: 5px 50px 0px 0px;
}

#newsletterform input {
    padding: 10px 18px!important
}

#newsletterform label {
    color:#fff;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.25);
    font-size:12px
}

a#button-newsletter {
    color:#fff;
    padding:11px 32px 10px 32px;
    background:#111;
    display:block;
    float:left;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-left: 78px;
    font-size:14px
}

a:hover#button-newsletter {
    text-decoration:none;
    background:#222
}
```

Comment: Browser? Version? Plattform?

Comment: Google chrome latest version (28.0.1500.72 m)

Comment: inputs as well as labels are inline elements. The easiest solution for that would be using an unordered list. Your button is not centered in any way in any screen size. You have set a margin-left, and that it the point where it will stay, no matter how you change your screen. You should seriously read a bit about the theory of responsive designs. By the way, your last div is not closed.

Comment: Yeah i have been struggling with that i have tried clear:both, block, block-inline en margin positions of the elements

Comment: fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/zCACF/

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML had tons of errors in there, unclosed elements and mismatched closings.

```
<div class="container">
<form method="post" action="#" id="newsletterform" data-mailchimp="xtrue">
    <div>
        <label for="newsletter-name"></label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Name" class="input-field" id="newsletter-name" name="newsletter-name" value="" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="newsletter-email"></label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="e-mail" class="input-field" id="newsletter-email" name="newsletter-email" value="" />
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="input-check">
        <label for="newsletter-checkbox1"></label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="input-check" id="newsletter-checkbox" name="newsletter-checkbox" value="check" /> <span class="span-style">some text to check</span>

    </div>
    <div class="input-check">
        <input type="checkbox" class="input-check" id="newsletter-checkbox" name="newsletter-checkbox2" value="check" /> <span class="span-style">some text to check2</span>

    </div>
    <div> <a id="button-newsletter" href="#" title="Subscribe now">Subscribe</a>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</form>
```

Just cleaning it up fixed it. I also split the `div class="input check"` for the two checkboxes into two divs, they now resize when screen is resized. Also, don't do inline CSS, it's hard enough to see what is going on with excess CSS in the css file without having to dig in the HTML as well. I commented out some CSS that had floats which are really unnecessary.

```
    .container {
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:500px;
}
/* #newsletterform {
    float: right;
    margin-top: -87px
} */

/* #newsletterform div {
    height: 45px;
    float: left;
    margin: 5px 50px 0px 0px;
} */
 #newsletterform input {
    padding: 10px 18px!important
}
#newsletterform label {
    color:#fff;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
    font-size:12px
}
a#button-newsletter {
    color:#fff;
    padding:11px 32px 10px 32px;
    background:#111;
    display:block;
    float:right;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-left: 78px;
    font-size:14px
}
a:hover#button-newsletter {
    text-decoration:none;
    background:#222
}
.span-style {
    /*  width:120px; */
    margin-top:30px;
    display:inline-block;
}
.clear {
    clear:both;
}
```

JS fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/feitla/6TGM7/